# App Crash after change price of in app-purchase but works when debug from Xcode to device and simulator

Tags: swift, storekit

I just finish uploading my app to app store weeks ago, but just yesterday I just change the price of non-consumable product from App Store Connect.

I have tried my app again from emulator and debug to real device from Xcode, everything works correctly the price also change to the price that I have changed in app store connect.

But when I download the app from App Store and trying to open the page of the product, it crashes. I don't know why this happen, i have not change any code in my app. I even resubmitted my app to App Store but the result is still the same, it crashes at the page that showes the price of the product.

As for the code to fetch the product and show the price, here is my code:

```
enum Product: String, CaseIterable {
    case membershippayment = "com.myproducts"
}

func fetchProducts() {
    
    let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: Set(Product.allCases.compactMap({ $0.rawValue })))
    request.delegate = self
    request.start()
    
}


func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
     
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.models = response.products
         
        
        let product = response.products.first 
        let price = product!.price
        let int: Int = Int(truncating: price)
        let intFormatted = int.formattedWithSeparator
        
        self.txtPrice.text = "Rp. \(intFormatted)"
        self.Price_Payment = "\(price)"
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Just change line
`let price = product!.price` into `let price = product?.price ?? 0`

and reupload the app to the app store, it looks like the price returning nil value when the app is uploaded to the app store because the displayed text show "0"
why did this happen, do I need to do additional things in-app store connect?
I don't know if this matters, but the In-App Purchase product has the status "Missing Compliance", is it because of that? and if it is, how do I solve it?

Comment: Why are you force-unwrapping `response.products.first`?

Comment: @ElTomato to be honest i just following a tutorial, but when i remove the "!" it give me warning and i just press the "Fix" button to shut the warning down

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you did not change your app version in your build gradle. It should be add 1 number every you update the app

Gradle scripts -> build.gradle (Module: ...) -> find :

android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.barcodescanner3"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Change the versionCode and the versionName. Version name can be (1.1,1.2,1.3) but version code only allows integer (1,2,3)

Hope that help, sorry for my bad english

Comment: Sorry, I'm not create an android app but IOS app, and i also have change the build number before upload to the app store

Comment: I see, i'm sorry